# What is kriyacitta according to various Buddhist schools?

Tags: arahant

And to whom does it arise?
Also know as the Smile of the Arahant (hard to look On google)

Asking for a friend. Pass this on wont you?

Comment: My guess is that it is some kind of conceit or wrong self view?

Comment: A later Abhidhamma invention, Nyom http://www.palikanon.com/english/wtb/g_m/kiriya.htm (Brah google knows ones usual desires...)

Comment: See also a deeper discussion: "['The Kamma of Arahants'!!](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,9501.0.html)

Comment: [kiriya](http://accesstoinsight.eu/en/dictionary/kiriya) might contain useful crosslinks.

Comment: No, that's just conventional knowlegde. But to distinguish good and bad, of course a ordinary person whould not easily know, yet could take on it in faith at first place.

Comment: Arahants have neither conceit nor wrong view

Comment: Worldling aren't able to recognice such even in themselfs: something to consider...

Comment: At least they do not take what isn't given, and don't speak in praise of what is based on wrong view, encourage others to wong doing: something that could be of help for ordinary people to observe...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Kriya citta* is functional consciousness, meaning it performs a function without being karmically potent. In an arahant, it replaces kusala citta. An arahant does not create karma so their seemingly wholesome mind states are called *kriya* (functional).

Specifically, there are eight types of *sahetuka-kāmāvacara-kriyā-citta* - functional consciousness in the sensual sphere which have wholesome roots (non-greed, non-anger, non-delusion) and nine *sahetuka-kriyā--jhāna-citta* corresponding to the nine jhāna which also have wholesome roots. All of these arise only in arahants.

There are three additional *ahetuka-kriyā-citta* (rootless functional consciousness), one of which is the smile producing consciousness that occurs only to arahants. The other two are the adverting consciousnesses present in every mind process.

Comment: So only for an arahant then? Kriya citta does not arise to a monastic?

Comment: It's good to mention that it is an Abhidhamma and post canon term, not really finding a justification in this use in the Suttas, good Brahman.

Comment: The last two types mentioned occur in everyone, the rest only occur in arahants (including buddhas and private buddhas).